# How can one derive a partial differential equation from a function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parabolic-pde

## The Problem

If you are given a nonlinear PDE

$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} = D\nabla^2c + \alpha c \, \, \,, \vec{r} \in \Omega, \,\, \, t\gt 0 \, \, \, \, (1)$$
where $D, \alpha$  are constants.

And then you are introduced a function defined by:
$$\phi(\vec{r}, t) = c(\vec{r}, t)e^{-\alpha t} \, \, \, \, (2)$$
where $c$ satisfies $(1)$.

You are asked to **derive the PDE for the function $\phi$**

How does one solve this? My attempt is given below, but I have no proper idea of what I am doing.

---

### My attempt

I find a way to express $c$ in terms of $\phi$:
$$c = \phi e^{\alpha t} \, \, \, \, (3)$$
Then I just insert $(3)$ into $(1)$ to get:
$$\frac{\partial(\phi e^{\alpha t})}{dt} = D\nabla^2\phi e^{\alpha t} + \alpha \phi e^{\alpha t}  \, \, \, \, (4)$$

Is this the solution, or are there more steps to the problem? If someone could give me a guiding hand I would appreciate it very much.

---

### Continuation after assitance from user Ninad Munshi

$$e^{\alpha t}\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}+ \alpha \phi e^{\alpha t} = D\nabla ^2 \phi e^{\alpha t} + \alpha \phi e^{at} $$
Dividing by $e^{\alpha t}$
$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}+ \alpha \phi = D\nabla ^2 \phi + \alpha \phi $$
Taking $- \alpha \phi$ on both sides
$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t} - D\nabla ^2 \phi = 0  $$
$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t} - D\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2} = 0  $$

Comment: As a minor point, that PDE looks pretty linear to me. But yes you can continue on with what you were doing - except fix your exponential, it's incorrect.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I see, thank you! The linear part was given by the teacher so I took it for granted. I will fix the exponentials. Shall I continue simplifying (4) or does one stop at that point?

Comment: No you keep going, there is a simplification to be had. There should be no exponentials left.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Thank you very  much! I believe I have come to the proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new solution is right. You may recognize $\phi=c e^{-\alpha t}$ from the method of integrating factors for solving the ODE in $t$,
$$ \frac{dc}{dt}(t) - \alpha c(t) = f(t).$$
Your exercise is essentially an application of this to the new setting of a certain PDE. It somehow worked out because $\nabla^2 \phi = (\nabla^2 c)e^{-\alpha t}$, by which I mean that this change of variables simplifies the equation from $(\partial_t - \alpha -D\nabla^2)c=0$ to the same equation (for $\phi$) but with $\alpha=0$. Since knowing $\phi$ tells you everything about $c$, it suffices to study the $\alpha=0$ case.

This is not what happens if $\alpha=\alpha(x)$ was a function of $x$; going through the same motions, if we set $\phi(x,t) = c(x,t)e^{-a(x)t}$, we get instead
$$e^{\alpha(x)t}\partial_t \phi  =(\partial_t-\alpha(x)) (\phi e^{\alpha(x)t}) = D\nabla^2(\phi e^{\alpha(x)t}) = e^{\alpha(x)t}D\left[\nabla^2 \phi + 2\nabla\alpha\cdot\nabla \phi + \phi \nabla^2 \alpha + \phi|\nabla \alpha|^2\right]$$
which does not lead to a  simpler equation.

Comment: I did not actually see that. That is very cool. Do you have the time to elaborate on why $\nabla^2 \phi = (\nabla^2 c)e^{-\alpha t}$ made it work?

Comment: @Sonofgreek I tried to expand a little on what I meant